# Given key-value content, how do I group values by key and sort by value?

Tags: command-line, unix, shell-script, bash-scripting, sorting

I've the following sample input format (file or stdin):

```
key1: 1
key2: 2
key3: 3
key1: 4
key2: 5
key3: 6
```

Is there any few-liner which can group values based on the key and then sort?

Expected output would be either table:

```
key1 key2 key3
1    2    3
4    5    6
```

which can be afterwards sorted by column (e.g. `sort -k2`). Similar to this [example](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/121718/21471).

Or in similar format, like:

```
key1: 1 4
key2: 2 5
key3: 3 6
```

What's the easiest way to achieve that transformation?

Comment: Assuming the initial key sort (`sort -k1,1 -k2`) which also would result in sorted values (so you could just `sort` without any `-k` option), then the problem is simplified to merging lines with the same prefix; see http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/47786/concatenate-lines-by-first-column-awk-or-sed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems a work for `awk`. It allows somehow the use of associative multidimensional arrays.
The following bash script should do the work.

```
awk ' { Nb[$1]++;b[$1][Nb[$1]]=$2 }       
      END{ for (i in Nb) {                
        printf("%s ", i);               
        for (j = 1 ; j<=Nb[i]; j++) printf("%ld ", b[i][j]);
       printf(" \n") ; }   
      }' aaa.txt  | sort
```

**Some notes:**

- In the first part `{...}` it scans all the external file `aaa.txt` and load the arrays `b[][]` and the number of occurrences for each key `Nb[]`(maybe you have 4 instances of key3 and 12 of key1...).
- In the `END{...}` part for each key found `for (i in Nb)` print the key with no *newline* (`printf(...)`) then for each entry with index 1..Nb[i], it will print the value. Finally print a newline.
- The final pipe `|` will sort the output

  ```
  key1: 1 4  
  key2: 2 5  
  key3: 3 6
  ```
- Of course if are needed different layouts it's possible to build them starting from the example above and changing the nesting order of the for cycles.

Answer (score 0):

When key list is fixed, it can be transposed by the following command:

```
$ pr -mt <(grep key1 in.txt | cut -f2 -d:) <(grep key2 in.txt | cut -f2 -d:) <(grep key3 in.txt | cut -f2 -d:) | sort -k1
1            2           3
4            5           6
```

This can be improved further more to make it more flexible by using [eval](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/198903/21471).